# add and remove div with click event

Tags: jquery, show-hide

i have to add 2 div one by one on click event after this the add button will be disable and when i remove the first or second added div the add button will be enable here is my code..
here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arun_/XeSnu/5/)

**HTML**

```
<a id="addMoreroom" class="fnt-size13" href="#">+ Add Rooms</a>
<div id="roomDiv-1" class="rowG clearfix hide">                                              
    <label>Selected Room Type</label>
        <select>
           <option>1</option>
        </select>
    <label>Number Of Rooms</label>
        <select>
           <option>3</option>
        </select>
    <a id="rmoveRoom_1" class="fnt-size13" href="#">- Remove</a>
</div>
<div id="roomDiv-2" class="rowG clearfix hide">                                            
    <label>Selected Room Type</label>
        <select>
           <option>1</option>
        </select>
    <label>Number Of Rooms</label>
        <select>
           <option>3</option>
        </select>
    <a id="rmoveRoom_2" class="fnt-size13" href="#">- Remove</a>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#addMoreroom").click(function () {
    $('#roomDiv-1').addClass('show');
    $('#addMoreroom').attr('id', 'addMoreroom1');
    $("#addMoreroom1").click(function () {
        $('#roomDiv-2').addClass('show');
        $(this).hide();
        return false;
    });
});
$("#rmoveRoom_1").click(function () {
    $('#roomDiv-1').remove();
    $('#addMoreroom1').show();
    return false;
});

$("#rmoveRoom_2").click(function () {
    $('#roomDiv-2').remove();
    $('#addMoreroom').show();
    $('#addMoreroom1').attr('id', 'addMoreroom');
    return false;
});
});
```

the problem is whenever i click on remove button the loop will sucked and add button will be not visible please provide me some suggestion..

Comment: Why the "jquery-ajax" tag?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arun_/XeSnu/5/

Comment: please clarify if u multiple add or at a time once?

Answer (score 0):

I highly advise you not to nest `.click();` event handlers if possible. They tend to dupe AJAX requests and do all kinds of wacky stuff when nested.

Example in this case:

```
$("#addMoreroom").on("click", function () {
    $('#roomDiv-1').addClass('show');
    $('#addMoreroom').attr('id', 'addMoreroom1');
});

$("#rmoveRoom_1").on("click", function () {
    $('#roomDiv-1').remove();
    $('#addMoreroom1').show();
});

$("#addMoreroom1").on("click", function () {
    $('#roomDiv-2').addClass('show');
    $(this).hide();
});

$("#rmoveRoom_2").on("click", function () {
    $('#roomDiv-2').remove();
    $('#addMoreroom1').attr('id', 'addMoreroom');
    $('#addMoreroom').show();
});
```

I also think `return false;` isn't necessary, I mostly use it to terminate functions on conditions. Why use `.on();`? `.live();` is deprecated and you are dinamically changing DOM.

Fiddle doesn't work for me but I think you might get an error of non-existant IDs.

Final edit, added visibility for add button, fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9aBAe/2/:

```
$(document).on("click","#addMoreroom", function () {
    if($('#roomDiv-1').css("display") == "none")
    {            
        $('#roomDiv-1').show();
    }
    else if($('#roomDiv-2').css("display") == "none")
    {
        $('#roomDiv-2').show();
    }
});

$(document).on("click","#rmoveRoom_1", function () {
    $('#roomDiv-1').hide();
});

$(document).on("click","#rmoveRoom_2", function () {
    $('#roomDiv-2').hide();
});

$(document).on("click","a", function () {
    if($('#roomDiv-1').css("display") == "none" && $('#roomDiv-2').css("display") == "none")
    {
        $("#addMoreroom").show();        
    }
    else if ($('#roomDiv-1').css("display") == "none" || $('#roomDiv-2').css("display") == "none")
    {
       $("#addMoreroom").show(); 
    }
    else
    {
        $("#addMoreroom").hide();     
    }

});
```

Comment: any suggestion to do this functionality

Comment: check my last edit, should work good, could be little more optimized, last function could use of caching, but its good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you ask I guess. This [link](http://jsfiddle.net/XeSnu/17/). 
And here is code.

```
var addRoomCounter = 2;
$("#addMoreroom").click(function () {
    if(addRoomCounter == 2)
    {    
        $('#roomDiv-1').show();
    }
    if(addRoomCounter == 1)
    {    
        $('#roomDiv-2').show();
        $(this).hide();
    }
    addRoomCounter=addRoomCounter-1;
});

$("#rmoveRoom_1").click(function () {
    $('#roomDiv-1').hide();
    if(addRoomCounter == 0)
    {
        $('#addMoreroom').show();
    }
    addRoomCounter=addRoomCounter+1;
});

$("#rmoveRoom_2").click(function () {
    $('#roomDiv-2').hide()
    if(addRoomCounter == 0)
    {
        $('#addMoreroom').show();
    } 
    addRoomCounter=addRoomCounter+1;
});
```

You did only one thing wrong. You use remove function for element. It removes element from html document. SO you cannot call it again. In my case i just replace remove function with removeClass('show') and call addClass('hide')

Comment: i want same thing but please check it once again the loop get broken when remove the rooms

Comment: good going but when remove the both rooms and trying to add from beginning only one room is added and remove please check lil bit more..

Comment: look like this-->

when first click on add button roomDiv1 added
when second click on add button roomDiv2 added and add button disable

when remove roomDiv1 the div remove and add button enable
when remove roomDiv2 the div remove and add button enable


the same process will continues repeat

Comment: I do not understand. :( Can you clarify?

Comment: So you have a#add button. And dvi#one and div#two right? When you click first time to a#add button it will show div#one. Second time div#two and a#add will be disabled right? Some when you remove one of div#one or div#two -> a#add will appear. And when you close last div#one or div#two only a#add will remain in document. Right? And if you click it it will show again one of div's? Right?

Comment: Check my [link](http://jsfiddle.net/XeSnu/17/) I already updated. I guess you did not check updated answer above.

Comment: So last version as you expected or not?

Answer (score 0):

use jquery's `show()` and `hide()` and `toggle()` functions, you dont have to define your own css, since these functions will take care of it..

http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working code:

**Html:**

```
<a id="addMoreroom" class="fnt-size13" href="#">+ Add Rooms</a>
  <div id="parentroom">
  </div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).on("click","#addMoreroom",function() {
            var div1=$('#roomDiv-1').html();
              if($("#parentroom #roomDiv-1").length>1){                  
                $("#addMoreroom").attr('disabled',true);   
              }else{
                $("#parentroom").append("<div id='roomDiv-1' class='rowG clearfix hide'><label>Selected Room Type</label><select><option>1</option></select><label>Number Of Rooms</label><select><option>3</option></select><a id='rmoveRoom_1' class='fnt-size13' href='#'>- Remove</a></div>");
           }
      });                  
     $("#parentroom").on("click","#rmoveRoom_1",function() {
         if($(this).parent().index()==0 ||$(this).parent().index()==1){
            $("#addMoreroom").prop('disabled',false);
         }
         $(this).closest($("#parentroom #roomDiv-1")).remove();
            return false;

        });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/M7nM8/